# How can I set a default contact for a phone number on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

In my contact list, I have a number of contacts that share the same work phone number (synchronized from exchange server), because they are work colleagues. For instance:

1. James (Employee #1)
2. George (Employee #2)
3. Sarah (Employee #3)

the work name

I keep the home phone number for each contact so that when I want to speak to one of them, I can choose the contact and then where to try to reach them. I keep a separate contact for the work so that I can call there when I don't want to talk to anybody specific.

When anybody calls from the work  phone, I want the phone to display the work contact, not anybody in particular. Is there any way to specify that a phone number has a default contact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Open contacts
2. Find the record for you. If you don't have a record for yourself, create one.
3. Enter the work phone the employees will be calling from into one of your number phone slots.

Now, when the phone rings, it will say something like "Work or 3 others."

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have to deal with a number that could be any one of a number of people, all behind the same corporate number, I set it up as a separate contact, by the company name & remove it from each individual.

That way, if anyone from the company calls, it says the company name. It can't say an individual's name because there's only one recognisable incoming number, so I remove that from the equation.

If I need to call anyone at the company who doesn't have a direct dial number, that's the one I ask Siri for - 'ring TheCompany',
otherwise I'd say 'ring John at Work' to get his direct dial.